# What is a good process when diagnosing a transmission problem?

Tags: transmission, noise, chrysler, sebring, slipping

Just bought a 2002 Chrysler Sebring LX as a project car.  The main problem is the transmission keeps slipping and the TCM is sending trouble codes.  There also a loud, high pitched whine that seemingly comes from the transaxle where my CV joint connects to the tranny.  I've been doing some research on the web and it seems that transmission problems on 01-03 Dodge/Chrysler are all too common.  There must be at least 20 suggestions that users on various forums claim to have fixed the problem... So I figure I come back here to this forum to get a clearer, more definitive answer my particular problem.  I would just like to start by making sure that I narrow down my list possible fixes by following a good transmission diagnosis procedure... Any suggestions?

Things I HAVE done:

- Pulled codes (p0700,p1684)
- Checked ATF level (topped off, but not over filled)
- Reset TCM
- Checked for leaks (none)

Comment: p0700 is a transmission mil request code you need an enhanced obd2 scanner to pull the codes from the tcm before you begin doing any other diagnostics.

Comment: Could you elaborate further?  The tool pulls additional codes other than what I already have?

Comment: generic obd2 scanners only interact with the pcm. to pull codes from the transmission or other computers you need a scanner that will communicate with those other computers. it may be cheaper to have someone with such a scanner to pull the codes for you rather than buying one.

Comment: Confirmed that indeed p0700 is a generic transmission fault code... Thanks,  I'll take it over to AutoZone in the morning and post the results.

Comment: autozone probably won't be able to tell you more than you already know. try calling a independent shop and see if they'll pull the codes for free or for a half hour of labor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got anyway to check pressure that tourqe putting out .my nice had one doing same exact thing hers turned out to be torque converter .it was winning slipping then finally quit pulling .I had to put it in for her or I would have never believed it . thought it was a bearing .

Answer (score 0):

When there are non-catastrophic malfunctions in drive-train components such as engines, transmissions, and axles, the malfunction falls under the **drive-ability** diagnosis category. I'd say the problems with your transmission are in that category.

The most exhaustive form of diagnosis is to source a Chrysler factory service manual and follow the troubleshooting tree for your specific problems. I've had luck finding service manuals on eBay. You can also check out your local public library. If no luck at the library, then you can check any nearby trade schools or community colleges. If the institutions have any form of automotive technology programs, then you can ask and see if they have any old manuals they'd be willing to part with.

The diagnostic trouble codes (DTCs) you find will point you in the right direction. Once you source a manual there is a section that outlines all of the applicable trouble codes. Find the code you have and there is a long list of procedures to carry out to pinpoint the root cause. (I speculate the high-pitched whine is a worn or dry bearing)

Comment: oil cavitation could also produce a sound like that. Alldata DIY is a website that offers online vehicle factory service manuals and information, albeit difficult to learn to navigate, for an affordable "per vehicle" subscription. You'd find the troubleshooting guide there. +1 on the long list of procedures mentioned above.